# Custom model (R6 class) with caret giving binding error

Tags: r, r-caret

I have created a custom model using R6 class. Due to the proprietary nature of work, I cant share the code but can share the anonymized structure. So basically, you would instantiate the model as follows

```
mod = my_model$new(formula = form, data = data, hyper1 = hyper1, hyper2 = hyper2)
```

Arguments:
formula: Standard R formula
data: Data Frame containing X and y values
hyper1 and hyper2: hyper-parameters of this model

Now, I am trying to integrate this with the `caret` package and having issues during the training process. This is the fit function that I am using

```
fitFunc <- function(x, y, wts, param, lev, last, weights, classProbs, ...) {

  # Custom algorithm takes dataframe as input so need to convert 'x' and 'y' to a dataframe
  # https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89171/help-requested-with-using-custom-model-in-caret-package
  data = as.data.frame(x)
  data$.outcome = y
  data = as.data.frame(data)

  # Define formula for model
  form = formula(.outcome ~ .)

  mod = my_model$new(formula = form, data = data, hyper1 = param$hyper1, hyper2 = param$hyper2, ...)

  return(mod)
}
```

This is the code snippet for integrating the custom model with caret and running it.

```
library(caret)
set.seed(998)
inTraining <- createDataPartition(mtcars$mpg, p = .75, list = FALSE)
training <- mtcars[ inTraining,]
testing  <- mtcars[-inTraining,]

fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3)

set.seed(825)

mdl_builder = train(mpg ~ ., data = training,
                    method = custom_model_list,
                    tuneLength = 8,
                    trControl = fitControl)
```

However, this leads to the following error messages (just a small snippet, it actually fails on every fold)

```
model fit failed for Fold2: hyper1=1, hyper2=4 Error in modelFit$xNames <- colnames(x) : 
  cannot add bindings to a locked environment
```

I think this is coming from the fact that the caret code internally is trying to assign the xNames to the R6 class object but the R6 class is not allowing this. I dont understand how to fix this (if at all it is possible). Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out right after typing this question (+ a little more research)

The key was to set `lock_objects = FALSE` in the R6 class to that new attributes can be added from outside.